# How to set "keep with next" property on a table using Novacode DocX?

Tags: c#, docx, novacode-docx

In Word there is a property "keep with next" under Paragraph > Line and Page Breaks. I was wondering if there is a way to set this property to a table created using Novacode DocX

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set the paragraph of at least one cell in every row in the table using KeepWithNext(true).  If you are building your tables dynamically, then this is easy to do.

```
Novacode.Table t = doc.InsertTable(2, 3); // 2 rows; 3 columns

t.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].Append("A1").KeepWithNext(true);
t.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs[0].Append("B1");
t.Rows[0].Cells[2].Paragraphs[0].Append("C1");
t.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].KeepWithNext(true);

t.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].Append("A2").KeepWithNext(true);
t.Rows[1].Cells[1].Paragraphs[0].Append("B2");
t.Rows[1].Cells[2].Paragraphs[0].Append("C2");
```